# The server requested authentication method unknown to the client [caching_sha2_password]

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

Tengo instalados MySQL 8 y Laravel 5.6.18; cuando trato de ejecutar las migraciones con: `php artisan migrate`

Un ejemplo de mis migraciones es:

```
Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('nombre')->unique()->index();
            $table->string('descripcion', 500);
            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')
                ->onDelete('cascade')
                ->onUpdate('cascade');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

Comento: el orden de mis migraciones es correcto es decir primero tengo la migración users, luego categories y luego posts

Sin embargo obtengo el siguiente error

> PDOException::("PDO::__construct(): The server requested
>   authentication method unknown to the client [caching_sha2_password]").

Cabe señalar que con la versión 5.7 de MysqL ejecuto las migraciones sin problema alguno

Comment: Checa mi respuesta en https://stackoverflow.com/a/58615936/6312647 para Ubuntu

Answer (score 9, accepted):

El problema es que cambió la autenticación predeterminada en MySQL 8, lo cual genera dicho error.

Para solucionarlo se sugieren ejecutar las siguientes líneas, o solo la primera parte de ellas, según el caso, obviamente hay que reemplazar `user` y `password` por los valores adecuados:

```
CREATE USER 'user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'password';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'user'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;

CREATE USER 'user'@'%' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'password';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'user'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

Answer (score 3):

Esto funcionó para mi:

Primero creé un nuevo usuario:

```
CREATE USER 'user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'password';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'user'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;

CREATE USER 'user'@'%' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'password';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'user'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

Después configuré el archivo *config/database.php* (https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/23948):

```
'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'base_de_datos'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'user'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'password'),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
            'modes'  => [
                'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY',
                'STRICT_TRANS_TABLES',
                'NO_ZERO_IN_DATE',
                'NO_ZERO_DATE',
                'ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO',
                'NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION',
            ],

        ],
```

Y por último configuré el *.env* :

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=base_de_datos
DB_USERNAME=user
DB_PASSWORD=password
```

Listo!!!

Answer (score 0):

Para MySql 8 lo he solucionado cambiando el método de autentificación en la configuración al momento de realizar el proceso de instalación. Quedando de la siguiente manera:

[image: configuracion de mysql8]

Answer (score 0):

Para mi funciono el comando de sql

```
ALTER  'user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'password';
```

y leí la [reseña de](https://bobcares.com/blog/mysql-the-server-requested-authentication-method-unknown-to-the-client/)

Comment: You're at SO en español, so please answer only in spanish

Comment: Sofia, si la pregunta es en español, porque la respuesta es en ingles?